# Drop fragmented packets in nftables

Tags: networking, iptables, ipv4, packets, nftables

Using iptables is it possible to block fragmented packets with this rule:

```
iptables -A INPUT -f -j DROP
```

But there isn't a equivalent in nftables. There is any way to do it?

Comment: For my own curiosity: why do you want to drop them?

Comment: Most likely to see what breaks and watch the fires burn...

Answer (score 4):

From [Nftables Wiki](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Quick_reference-nftables_in_10_minutes#Ip) or just `man nft` you can use `ip frag-off`. Now (after a few trials and errors) the 3 flags (reserved, DF, MF) are included in this value at the 3 highest bits and have to be excluded from the test, needing a `&` operation. So this:

```
nft 'add rule ip filter input ip frag-off & 0x1fff != 0 drop'
```

Would do it...

... but when nf_conntrack_ipv4 is loaded (almost always), its specific nf_defrag_ipv4 part registers at [hook priority -400](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/include/uapi/linux/netfilter_ipv4.h?h=linux-4.8.y), and will reassemble all fragments. That means any processing after won't see any fragment. So your chain has to hook with a priority value lower than that. Here's a complete working example:

```
nft add table filter
nft 'add chain filter predefrag { type filter hook prerouting priority -450; }'
nft 'add rule ip filter predefrag ip frag-off & 0x1fff != 0 drop'
```

Arguably the 1st packet is also a fragment with offset 0 but with MF set. So maybe `0x1fff` should be replaced with `0x3fff` to catch it.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
iptables-translate -A INPUT -f -j DROP
```

result:

```
nft add rule ip filter INPUT ip frag-off != 0 counter drop
```

iptables-translate comme from (on debian Debian 4.9.82-1+deb9u3 (2018-03-02) x86_64 GNU/Linux:

apt install iptables-nftables-compat

https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Configuring_chains#Base_chain_priority

or 
nft 'add rule inet filter input ip frag-off 0x4000 counter accept'

Comment: today's result of iptables-translate is different (meaning the older translation was wrong): `iptables-translate -A INPUT -f -j DROP` => `nft add rule ip filter INPUT ip frag-off & 0x1fff != 0 counter drop` which is what I wrote 1y1/2 before.